How to implement a preprocessor for code in python
I have some code an want to scan i line by line. The problem is that in code, statements are build up over several lines, like
def UART(ONE):                              
    ONE = UUUU001 + 4   
    print(ONE)   

I would like to have a tool which would scan the code and prepare it for me to work on it, extract names, calls, parameters, etc. I've got the hint to use ast, but I have the impression as if I do not understand ast very well
For example, I made a class MyVisitor which should do the preprocessing part, but I am not able to get the correct statements from code because "If", Function Definitions, For-Loops are not recursive visited and therefore are appearing as on line (shown in the output). (On the other hand, function calls are assembled to one statement). So what am i missing?

class MyVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.konvertiert = []
    def generic_visit(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Constant):
            pass
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Store):
            pass
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Load):
            pass
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Name):
            pass
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Attribute):
            pass
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
            self.konvertiert.append(ast.unparse(node))
        elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):
            pass
        elif isinstance(node, ast.If):
            self.konvertiert.append(ast.unparse(node))
            #super().generic_visit(node)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Call):
            self.konvertiert.append(ast.unparse(node))
            #super().generic_visit(node)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
            self.konvertiert.append(ast.unparse(node))
            #super().generic_visit(node)
        else:
            super().generic_visit(node)



code = ''' 
ONE = 7
if ONE==7:
    print('Found one')
open(file, line)
foo = abrakdabra(15, 5, 
                    16, 67,
                    eins, 99)
result = get_nummer(142, 141, 140)        # 10
def UART(ONE):                              # 11
    ONE = UUUU001 + 4
    print(ONE)
WWWWWWWW(eins, 32, irgendwas, 'a[6]')       # 12
name2 = 'Elise'                             # 13
'''

tree = ast.parse(code)
vis = MyVisitor()
vis.konvertiert = []
vis.visit(tree)

lauf = 0
for i in vis.konvertiert:
    lauf += 1
    print(f'{lauf}: {i}')


Output:
1: ONE = 7
2: if ONE == 7:
    print('Found one')
3: open(file, line)
4: foo = abrakdabra(15, 5, 16, 67, eins, 99)
5: result = get_nummer(142, 141, 140)
6: def UART(ONE):
    ONE = UUUU001 + 4
    print(ONE)
7: WWWWWWWW(eins, 32, irgendwas, 'a[6]')
8: name2 = 'Elise'

